# hierarchical information in doctrine and symfony 1.4

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine, symfony-1.4, hierarchical-data

i have an entity with a lot of fields(like facebook user Information with multiple levels like Basic Information, Contact Information, and...). and i want to use it exactly like facebook . i mean i want several tabs to put related fields in there. the easiest way is to store all of them in a table but it's too nasty . is there any way to do this better? i know something about database hierarchical design, but is there a way to do this in symfony 1.4 and use it's form creator either?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: where do you need help? In the view or in the model?

If you want it too look like Facebook, we're talking View. This has nothing to do with Symfony, but just HTML (with some CSS/JS probably).

If you're talking about how to store this information: the information your describing isn't "hierarchical". Hierarchical is about trees and things like that, most of the time with an almost infinite depth. 
Here you're talking about a strict structure (you, as developer, know exactly which fields you want to render, and define these yourself). You could look into Entity-Attribute-Value stores. But beware: when implementing some like this in mySQL, it won't be easy to do 'complex' queries. (Even a query like: "List all people in New York, older than 30 years old", is not rendered easy).

So why won't you go with a table with a lot of columns? There's nothing nasty about that! That you, as a human being, may have troubles viewing these data in phpMyAdmin, has nothing to do with how a computer manages this information ;-). You could split up the 'User' model in a seperate 'UserProfile' model (with a one-on-one relation), so you can easily refer to users on other pages (where you don't need all profile data).

Comment: i have no problem with storing all of them in one table. actually it works fine. i have even categorized it just like facebook in multiple tabs and ... . but i was worried about adding some stuff to it in the future. but one-to-one relation for User and UserProfile seems perfect. i will go for it. thanks a lot.

Comment: And with Doctrine Migrations, adding columns is a breeze ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Doctrine Nested sets.  It is basically a tree structure contained in your database.  I have a demo of how this can be used, but the source code might scare you.

Take a look at the demo to give you an idea of what you can do.  If you are leaning towards this option, then you should definitely check out the tutorial link I posted below to get started.

[Demo](http://cart.jgallant.com/cartadmin/categoryIndex)

[Source Code](https://github.com/jongallant/sfCartPlugin)

[Doctrine Nested Sets Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/hierarchical-data#nested-set)

[Tutorial on Nested Sets](http://halestock.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/symfony-implementing-a-nested-set-part-one/)

Comment: thanks for your detailed information. this way i'm  able to use symfony forms too? i mean if i set this nested schema, does symfony create different forms with related fields? cuz i want that.

Comment: by the way your demo was amazing! i will look at it ASAP. it must be so fun exploring in there!!!

Comment: I don't think this problem can be solved with Nested Sets. Unless you want to assign an "Address" model, to another "Address" model, which in turn has an "Address" parent, with another "Address" parent. Nested Set is a bahaviour for creating trees (with an unlimited depth).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The admin generator doesn't work well with Nested sets, however, you can override the forms that are generated to fine tune it to your needs.  If you are looking to get forms created on the fly for 'n' number of fields, you will need to invest a lot of time in creating a system that will do this.